# Remove array values from array based on content, PHP

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I'v got a string which I want to convert to an array so I can access the items in the string from the array.
When I echo the string it comes up as a normal string without spaces however when I convert it to an array using:

```
$array = explode(' ', $string);
```

and then echo it:

```
echo var_dump($array);
```

I get lots of array values that are either empty or have a space, How do I remove these values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is [`preg_split`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$array = preg_split('/\s+/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

It splits for any space and removes any empty parts.